# How We can do partial search in Redis using SSCAN with special characters

Tags: redis, node-redis, redis-cli

I have created a Redis set and the following is the member of the set:

```
 "[test@#$demo%^here[sfs]][en-us][1234]"
```

I have 1000 members in the Redis set and I want to search this document using sscan partially I have tried following the way

```
 sscan test 0 match "[test@#$demo%^here[sfs]][en-us]"
```

but is not working properly So how I can do it directly without looping?

Comment: help me here to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the \ to escape a character that has special meaning inside a match expression. You can try:

```
sscan test 0 match "\\[test@#$demo%^here\\[sfs]\\]\\[en-us\\]*"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but is any list of special chars that I need to escape? so as per that I will update my logic

Comment: List of special chars you can check [here](https://redis.io/commands/keys)

Comment: I think ., +, *, ?, ^, $, (, ), [, ], {, }, |, \ here are the list of special characters then I need to escape

Comment: any javascript function to replace all special characters with \\specialcharacter?

Comment: is  ., +, *, ?, ^, $, (, ), [, ], {, }, |, \ list is valid or any other characters is present?

Comment: It is working in the Redis terminal but it is not working for node .js code same query